# Homotopy type of $SO(4)/SO(2)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology

A classical result states that the quotient $SO(4)/SO(3)$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$. In fact, this can be stated in more general terms since $SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ has the homotopy type of $S^n$. What I don't know is what is the homotopy type of $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$ or even if it has a general formultation. The concrete case I am interested in is the one for $n=3$, i.e. the homotopy type of $SO(4)/SO(2)$. Or, at least if its first homotopy groups $\pi_k(SO(4)/SO(2))$ (for $k=1,2,3$) are known. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that $SO(4)/SO(3)$ is also $SO(4)/(SO(3)\times SO(1))$, and hence a natural extrapolation is rather $SO(4)/(SO(2)\times SO(2))$, which is the oriented 2-Grassmanian in $\mathbf{R}^4$. As regards $SO(4)/SO(2)$, it can be interpreted as the set of triples $(P,o,D)$ where $P$ is a 2-plane in $\mathbf{R}^4$, $D$ is a line in $P$ and $o$ is an orientation on $P$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) $V_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$. It fits into a fibration $S^2\to V_2(\mathbb{R}^4)\to S^3$ and so has trivial $\pi_1$. By playing around with the long exact sequence of this fibration I was able to show that $\pi_2(V_2(\mathbb{R}^4))\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_3(V_2(\mathbb{R}^4))\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ (but I don't know a reference off the top of my head).

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly what it is. I did not realise before asking but yes, it is pretty clear. In fact, $SO(n)/SO(k)$ should be $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Thanks a lot Mark Grant!

Comment: $V_2(R^4)$ is the unit tangent bundle of $S^3$. Since $S^3$ is paralelizable it is homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^3$.

Comment: A reference may be *Fiber Bundles* of Husemoller

Comment: Gustavo Granja yes, that was very precise. thank you!